# Обновление версии бд (миграции) SQLite

Tags: база-данных, .net, sqlite, архитектура

На данный момент в моем приложении используется MS SQL. в проекте на c# (net 3.5) есть проект базы данных. при необходимости изменения структуры бд, изменяется структура в этом проекте,затем выполняется SchemaCompare, с помощью которой можно обновить рабочую базу, плюс SchemaCompare генерирует скрипты, которые встраиваются в инсталятор, выполняются на машине клиента при обновлении ПО и обновляют базу клиенту. Теперь встал вопрос о переходе на какую-нибудь встроенную СУБД, поддерживающую представления (Views). Пока что выбор пал на SQLite (но он не окончательный). Так вот суть проблемы. Как и с помощью каких средств можно выполнять аналогичные действия для SQLlite (сравнение схем, обновление, генерация скриптов). Или подскажите, пожалуйста, какую-нибудь другую ВСТРОЕННУЮ субд и инструменты, с помощью которых можно достичь поставленных задач. Спасибо!

Comment: Вариант писать человеческие миграции, а не лезть в базу и генерить скрипты — не расматривается? :)

Comment: в конечном итоге рассматривается. но для большого проекта все же хочется как то облегчить себе жизнь. да и это не моя прихоть. начальство сказало, что надо так

Comment: Мне в принципе не нравится идея автогенерируемых скриптов миграции. Кроме как добавить или удалить оно же ничего не сможет. Как быть с переименованиями, разделениями, объединениями и прочими нетривиальными преобразованиями?

Answer (score 1):

Если возможно использование [entity framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/ef.aspx), то он предоставляет встроенный механизм [миграций](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) изменений структур БД. EF версии =>6.0 поддерживает СУБД SQLite. В своем проекте использую EF для работы с SQLite, проблем не вижу.
Кроме одной, технология [CodeFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj193542.aspx) не умеет генерировать таблицы автоматически, их необходимо создавать самому с помощью скриптов. Но это решается путем создания их в методе [OnModelCreating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder)) класса [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)